# Logstash date format

Tags: logstash

I am using logstash to parse json input message and then add another field from one of the parsed values:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "data"
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => {
        "index_date" => "%{[data][@timestamp]}}"
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but now I need index_date to be only the date.
How can I format the `[data][@timestamp]` field to only return the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the date_formatter plugin with

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-date
```

And then you can use something like this in your logstash filter function

```
date_formatter {
    source => "index_data"
    target => "[@metadata][indexDateOnlyDate]"
    pattern => "YYYY.MM.dd"}
```

This should work :)

Comment: actually it was "logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-date_formatter" this plugin